# Screenshot shortcut key error

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

For more than a week or so whenever I use one of the cursor keys, page up or down, home, end or delete, it takes a screenshot and asks if I want to save to clipboard.
I checked Ubuntu Keyboard shortcuts and it seems to have the default shortcuts (Print, Alt+Print, Shift+Print...).
I'm sure I don't have to tell you how annoying it is this behaviour when editing text or just trying to fast forward when viewing a video.
Thanks.
I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Screenshot 3.10.1.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Zorin 9.1 and I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>PRINT</kbd> keys and take a beautiful screenshot. I have shortcuts into **start // control panel // keyboard // shortcuts**.

If you can not then: You must have installed `gnome-screenshot` that you can search in the software center of Ubuntu, i take always screenshots with this program because it have a time (waiting in seconds) for take a screenshot.